# Passion flower leaves are turning yellow

Tags: leaves

What could be the reason of my Passion Flower leaves turning yellow? And what needs to be done? Thanks!
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add another picture showing the whole plant and its pot (assuming it is in a pot) please

Comment: Green veins and yellowing between is low Nitrogen ( one possible cause as I remember).

Comment: hi @Bamboo I have added more pictures.

Answer (score 1):

It needs a larger pot with new potting soil, it's run out of root room and nutrients. However, it seems to be flowering now (unless those images are not current) and you'd need to wait for flowering to stop before you pot on, but I'd recommend you pot on anyway, cut back by half to encourage new growth and just wait for new flowerbuds to form, which they will. These plants want to get 3-5 metres tall, so being in a very small pot means the foliage suffers and the growth is poor with only a single stem. Note that flowering is not necessarily a sign of health, in fact, flowers often form on sickly plants in an effort to reproduce because the plant is suffering.

Comment: Thank you! Let me repot and I will update with my findings.